# Continue iterating through sub-list after return?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, return, list-comprehension

I am trying to iterate through values in a list of lists to see if the innermost values obey certain rules:

- blank lists return ([ ], 'blank')
- lists with negative integers, floats, or strings return ([ ], 'non-digits')
- lists with combinations of positive integers and return as is.

the problem is that after returning the first value in the sub-list, the program skips all of the other values in that sub-list and goes to the next one, look at the current output further down to see what I mean.

```
    def getPapers(f, n):
    x = f.readlines() #read f to x with \n chars and whitespace
    strippedPaper = [line.strip("\n").replace(' ', '') for line in x] #stores formatted ballot 
    #print(strippedPaper)

    print()

    #Create list of lists from ballots.
    strippedBallot = [item.split(",") for item in strippedPaper]
    #print(strippedBallot)
    print()


    #Information passed to parsePaper
    try:
        for ballot in strippedBallot:
            print(ballot) #Show individual ballots
            valueParsePaper = parsePaper(ballot, n) #ballot is passed to parsePaper here.
            print(valueParsePaper) #Displays the value returned from parsePaper


    except TypeError:
        print("There was an error with the data type passed to var 'valueParsePaper'\n"
              "from this set.\n")    


def parsePaper(s, n):
    #If s is informal reutrn an empty list with an appropriate string
    try:
        if len(s) > n:
            tooLong = ([], "too long")
            return tooLong
        elif len(s) == 0:
            blankBallot = ([], "blank")
            return blankBallot
        #elif sum(s[:]) == 0:
            #blankBallot = ([], "blank")
            #return blankBallot

        else:            
            voteWorth = parseVote(s)
            #The vote inside the ballot is passed to parseVote

            #parseVote returns a value to voteWorth.

            if voteWorth == 0: #for empty/blank string

                return ([], "blank")

            elif voteWorth == int(-1): #for non-digits/invalid numbers
                return ([], "non-digits")

            else: #for valid votes
                return ([s], "") 

    except ValueError:
        print("There is an invalid value at parsePaper")


#parseVote(s) Returns vote from s, return 0 for empty vote, -1 for votes containing non-digits
#except spaces

def parseVote(s):
    try:
        for i in s:
            if i == ' ':
                return int(0) #for empty spaces, return to parsePaper

            elif i == '':
                return int(0) #for blanks, return to parsePaper

            elif i.isdigit() == False: #for non-digits
                return int(-1) #return to parsePaper

            elif int(i) < 0: #for negnative numbers
                return int(-1) #return to parsePaper

            else:
                return int(i) #return the positive integer to parsePaper
    except ValueError:
            print("The object passed to parseVote is invalid.")
```

This shows the input and output in pairs.

```
['']
([], 'blank')

['1', '2', '3', '4']
([['1', '2', '3', '4']], '')

['', '23', '']
([], 'blank')

['9', '-8']
([['9', '-8']], '')  

['thesepeople!']
([], 'non-digits')

['4', '', '4', '4']
([['4', '', '4', '4']], '')

['5', '5', '', '5', '5']
([['5', '5', '', '5', '5']], '')
```

First two lines are fine, it is blank and returns blank, next two lines *appear* fine because it returns values as is, but the third pair should not return ([ ], blank) because the input contains positive integers. You can also see that the 4th pair should return 'non-digits' because it contains a negative number.

After going through step by step, I find the function returns only the first value from each sub-list.

**What I need** is for the program to go through the same sub-list again and  check each value before it determines if a sub-list is valid - I'm unsure of how to check each sub-list value and THEN determine if the entire contents of that sub-list make it valid.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code contains a lot of irrelevant parts. Start with an example input, and example output, then reproduce your error in an example.

Comment: Thanks for reading, sorry I couldn't provide a more minimal example to this problem. I believe I have solved my own problem for now, so I am sharing my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to my own problem for anyone who may come across it:

By checking and appending each vote handed to parseVote() into a new list, and then passing that new list list back to parsePaper(), I have been able to make the adjustments I need.

Now ballots containing text or negative numbers are automatically invalidated, and ballots which add up to zero or considered blank.

```
def getPapers(f, n):
    x = f.readlines() #read f to x with \n chars and whitespace
    strippedPaper = [line.strip("\n").replace(' ', '') for line in x] #stores formatted ballot 
    #print(strippedPaper)

    print()

    #Create list of lists from ballots.
    strippedBallot = [item.split(",") for item in strippedPaper]
    #print(strippedBallot)
    print()

    #Information passed to parsePaper
    try:
        for ballot in strippedBallot:
            print(ballot) #Show individual ballots
            valueParsePaper = parsePaper(ballot, n) #Ballot is passed to parsePaper here.
            print(valueParsePaper) #print returned value


    except TypeError:
        print("There was an error with the data type passed to var 'valueParsePaper'\n"
              "from this set.\n")    


def parsePaper(s, n):
    #If s is informal reutrn an empty list with an appropriate string
    try:
        if len(s) > n:
            tooLong = ([], "too long")
            return tooLong
        elif len(s) == 0:
            blankBallot = ([], "blank")
            return blankBallot
        #elif sum(s[:]) == 0:
            #blankBallot = ([], "blank")
            #return blankBallot

        else:            
            voteWorth = parseVote(s)
            #The vote inside the ballot is passed to parseVote

            #parseVote returns a value to voteWorth.

            if voteWorth == 0: #for empty/blank string

                return ([], "blank")

            elif voteWorth == int(-1): #for non-digits/invalid numbers
                return ([], "non-digits")

            else: #for valid votes
                return (voteWorth, "") 

    except ValueError:
        print("There is an invalid value at parsePaper")


#parseVote(s) Returns vote from s, return 0 for empty vote, -1 for votes containing non-digits
#except spaces

def parseVote(s):
    try:
        voteWorthList = []
        for i in s:
            if i == ' ':
                i = 0
                voteWorthList.append(i)
                #return int(0) #for empty spaces, return to parsePaper

            elif i == '':
                i = 0
                voteWorthList.append(i)
                #return int(0) #for blanks, return to parsePaper

            elif i.isdigit() == False: #for non-digits
                i = int(-1)
                voteWorthList.append(i)
                #return int(-1) #return to parsePaper

            elif int(i) < 0: #for negnative numbers
                i = int(-1)
                voteWorthList.append(i)
                #return int(-1) #return to parsePaper

            else:
                i = int(i)
                voteWorthList.append(i)
                #return int(i) #return the positive integer to parsePaper
        print(voteWorthList)

        for i in voteWorthList:
            if i < 0:
                return int(-1)

        if sum(voteWorthList) == 0:
                return 0
        else:
            return voteWorthList

    except ValueError:
            print("The object passed to parseVote is invalid.")
```

New output is as such, showing the original input, the adjusted input, and final output:

```
['']
[0]
([], 'blank')

['1', '2', '3', '4']
[1, 2, 3, 4]
([1, 2, 3, 4], '')

['', '23', '']
[0, 23, 0]
([0, 23, 0], '')

['9', '-8']
[9, -1]
([], 'non-digits')

['thesepeople!']
[-1]
([], 'non-digits')

['4', '', '4', '4']
[4, 0, 4, 4]
([4, 0, 4, 4], '')

['5', '5', '', '5', '5']
[5, 5, 0, 5, 5]
([5, 5, 0, 5, 5], '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a shorter version if it would help. I hope this helps if I am understanding your problem correctly. Basically, you can do everything in one function rather than making 3

```
def getPapers(f, n):
    x = f.readlines()
    strippedPaper = [line.strip("\n").replace(' ', '') for line in x]
    ballot = tuple()
    allBlanks = False if [i.strip() for i in strippedPaper if i] else True
    if allBlanks:
        ballot = ([], "blank")
    elif len(strippedPaper) > n:
        ballot = ([], "too long")
    else:
        ballot = (strippedPaper, "")
        for i in strippedPaper:
            if i.strip() == '':
                continue 
            if not i.isdigit() or int(i) < 0:
                ballot = ([], "non-digits")
                break

    return ballot
```